# Grafana taking measurement as specified time

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a daily count metric being pushed to prometheus. Its important to have the measurement every few minutes, but I also want the measurement at a specified time (end of the day) to see the daily total. Is there a way to specify a time of the measurement?

I have set the `min_step` (time step) to be 24h. Doing so gives me measurements at 20:00:00 each day. Ideally this would be 23:50:00 through 23:59:59

The chart type is a Graph, and the PromQL query is:
`max(table_row_count) by (table)`
with min_step = 24h, format = time series, and min time interval = 24h. Relative time is set to 7d to get a weekly view of the tables.

I am expecting some way to be able to set the timestamp of the query that should be run every 24h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't have any cron features. You would have to revert to scheduling it yourself.

This means that the first requirement is to get the data you want at the given time. This can be easily done by a GET on the url of the metric you want. (by example using curl).

Now, the question is how to feed it to prometheus. I see three possibilities:

- dump the content in a file and let node exporter expose it to prometheus (and erase it after a time). A careful rewrite of metrics can be used in prometheus to sanitize it.
- write your own exporter to expose it (easy to do, especially since you have the right data format)
- push it to a push gateway but there is currently no way to make the data expire.